# A question of opinion: Are you still using iframes?

Tags: html, iframe, web-standards

Do iframes still fit the mold of current web standards? The technology is old but I am seeing them resurface - especially with the new youtube embed code being iframes and facebook just allowing custom tabs to be iframes as well.

My question is basically: Are the acceptable?

Comment: Yes, but now they're iFrames, and they're owned by Apple.

Comment: Oh, so now they release limited technology and get people to buy new versions, yearly, of what should have been sold originally? =p

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at this SO question: [Are IFrames (HTML) obsolete?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/755795/are-iframes-html-obsolete)

In short: They are part of the HTML 5 draft and will be sticking around. If used correctly, I think they are acceptable. :)

Answer (score 1):

I agree with everyone that they should be a last resort, but there are certain things that demand the use of iframes.

For instance, there's no better way to do ajax file uploading than posting to an iframe and then reacting to the iframe's onload event to handle it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, my company still uses iFrames to embed third-party content on our site.

They still have a place but, IMHO, should be a last resort.

Answer (score 0):

A lot of components such as Facebook's social widgets or Youtube's embeded player use iframes.

I also use some, when needed. Of course I don't abuse it because it's not adapted for all situations.