# When should I use div? When should I use frame? When should I use other forms of dynamic content?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, frame

I'm writing a web site with several forms of dynamic content. For instance, at the top, there are tabs for controlling which parts of the site are displayed below. And in a couple of pages, there are multiple select/option lists which change based on what has been selected in other select/option lists. Right now, I'm doing all of it with divs. I'm wondering if I should change some of it to frames. Are there other methods of changing this content? And when should I use what?
Thanks.

EDIT

To be more clear about my methods, when I say I'm "using divs" I mean I'm putting my content inside div blocks and updating them with jQuery.

Comment: Divs by themselves are NOT dynamic. Frames should be used as a last resort. jQuery provides all your dynamic needs, is there something specific you need?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

None of the things you mentioned require frames. 
Frames are from the past;-)

DIV's make a lot of sense for everything layout related.

Use javascript to do the dynamic option list thingies (either hide() or show() them using jquery  or use ajax to Load the different lists into the page)

Comment: There are some cases where they can't (sadly) be done without c.f. Facebook's 'Like' button.

Comment: Yes but then we're talking Iframes, I believe even CKeditor etc use iframes.... No problem with that at all;-)

Comment: I'd say 'fewer' rather than 'no' problems. C.f. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/755795/are-iframes-html-obsolete