# Change div content with link in another div

Tags: javascript, html

i have a menu bar with links which are in the header. when you click the link, i want to just change the content in the main div. i'm thinking of doing it in php, but you will have to reload the page. So i need to do it in javascript, but i dont know javascript.

here is my menu code in the header div:

```
<ul id="nav">
    <li><a href="#">Enter Information</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">View Records</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">View Upcoming</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: And where does the new content come from? Is it already in the page (add that to the code in your question), or from the server, requiring ajax? Does this need to be plain JavaScript, or would you be willing to use a library?

Comment: What kind of content do you need to load into the main div?

Comment: Time to learn some JavaScript.

Comment: the content will be a form for one link and basically a type of database for the other 2. I have a form.html file for the link for the form.

Comment: @Emily, Have you found the answer for your question?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the type of content, you have a few options available to you.  If you need to load a new page into the main content, you can use [iframes](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t2ByLmLnYJ8) and some javascript.  If you need to load simple text, you can simply use javascript.

Based on your feedback, you'll do something like this (note- I'm shooting from the hip regarding syntax, but this is generally what your code will need to look like):

```
<a href="#" onclick="UpdateIFrame('mypage.html')">Link 1</a>

<iframe id="MainContent">
</iframe>

<script>
   function UpdateIFrame( newPageAddress ){
     document.getElementById("MainContent").contentWindow.location = newPageAddress;
   }
</script>
```

Comment: i basically need to load pages if possible. what is the javascript that i will need?

Comment: I updated with code.  Keep in mind -- this is basic javascript and will accomplish what you want done...but at some point when you've developed a little more, you should use jquery and update the code.

Comment: Also, someone is eventually going to tell you not to use iframes.  I'm going to save them the trouble of argument and link to the already-had debate: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/755795/are-iframes-html-obsolete

Answer (score 0):

If you think about using PHP, I guess that you have to load dynamic content. For this, I advice you to use [AJAX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29)

The easiest is to use a framework, like the famous Jquery. Example [here](http://api.jquery.com/load/)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need any anchor elements. [W3 example](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_ajax1)

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.menu').click(function() {
            $("div").load('somecontent.txt');       
    });
});
</script>

<ul>
    <li class="menu">Enter Information</li>
    <li class="menu">View Records</li>
    <li class="menu">View Upcoming</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: But she **would** need **[tag:jquery]**; which isn't mentioned in her question. ***Or*** tagged therein.

Comment: Very true, maybe I'll try to edit later with a jqueryless example. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: this code snippet requires jquery, and the snippet is not a good example of how to create a menu.

Comment: I will use whatever I need to use. But the only thing i know is html and php

Answer (score 0):

here i am assuming that you get your content with a function call as `content()`

```
var list=document.getElementById('nav');
var links=list.getElementsByTagName('a');
var header=document.getElementById('header');
for (var i=0;i<links.length;i++)
{
links[i].onclick=function() {
header.innerHTML=content();       //here you can use something else to generate the content
}
}
```

Comment: I don't think using browser specific javascript is the best way to write a menu system.

Comment: @Jason wats browser specific in this?

Comment: in general this style of javascript will lead to a browser specific implementation, especially if one tries to develop a full featured menu system.  the power of frameworks like jquery is that they normalize the individual browsers javascript engine, so the developer doesn't have to deal with them.

Comment: @Jason i agree this will freak out IE users but will work well for DOM compliant browsers and he didnt say he wanted to use jquery

Answer (score 0):

You want to use [jquery](http://www.1stwebdesigner.com/css/38-jquery-and-css-drop-down-multi-level-menu-solutions/) to build something like this.  If you are serious about building web apps you need to learn how to use it (or a similiar framework like [MooTools](http://mootools.net/))

For this particular problem I would use an existing menuing system, here's the first list of  [jquery based menus](http://www.1stwebdesigner.com/css/38-jquery-and-css-drop-down-multi-level-menu-solutions/) that I found, but there are many more.

Answer (score -1):

In order to dynamicly load content (e.g. from a server using php/sql) without having to reload the website **Ajax** is exactly what you need.

Inlineframes (mentioned before), however,  should not be used for they are deprecated.

W3schools provides a very basic but straightforward [tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/default.asp) on Ajax.

Comment: Or you can put all the markup in one page within <div> tags that have the attribute style="display: none;" and use javascript to change the display to "block" while simultaneously setting other content areas to "none".  That is if your content sections are not very large.  Otherwise, dynamic content should be handled as Milten suggests.  Also, this is very easily handled either way with a javascript library like jQuery or Prototype.