# Can content in one div from menu bar

Tags: javascript, html

I have a menu bar with 3 links. When you click on those links, i want the content to change in the main div. The links will be to 3 different files. one of them is an html file and the other 2 are php files. I dont really know javascript, but this is what i have so far:

```
<ul id="nav">
<li><a href="#" id="link1" onclick="changeDiv('1')">View Records</a></li>
<li><a href="#" id="link2" onclick="changeDiv('2')">Enter Information</a></li>
<li><a href="#" id="link3" onclick="changeDiv('3')">View Upcoming</a></li>
</ul>
```

the javascript that i have is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   function changeDiv(link)
   {
      var contentDiv = $('#content');
      if (link == '1')
         contentDiv.html();
      if (link == '2')
         contentDiv.html();
      if (link == '3')
         contentDiv.html();

   }
</script>
```

and from there i have tried a bunch of different things, but now im stuck. What format does it all need to be in?

Comment: Same poster, related question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6850979/change-div-content-with-link-in-another-div

Answer (score 1):

you have to use jquery : include this in your header 

    
    
        $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#link1').click(function(){
            $('#main').load('ajax/test.html ');
        })

```
    $('#link2').click(function(){
        $('#main').load('ajax/test2.html ');
    })

    $('#link2').click(function(){
        $('#main').load('ajax/test3.php ');
    })

    })

</script>
```

```
<a id="link1" href="#">asd</a>
<div id="main"></div>
```

Comment: where would i put that in the file at?

Comment: where #result and #container is, what would go there? my content div is #main, so would that go where #content is?

Comment: just forgot about #container, and the #result in your case is #main

Comment: that still doesnt work. What kind of format should the files be that i am linking? like does the html file need to have all the basic html stuff like <title><head><body> etc?

Comment: are running on a server , or how ?

Comment: i am just viewing it in a browser.

Answer (score 0):

if your are using jQuery have a look to [jQuery.load()](http://api.jquery.com/load/). Your code should be something like this:

```
function changeDiv(link){
   if(link == '1') jQuery('#content').load('htmlPage1.html');
   if(link == '2') jQuery('#content').load('htmlPage2.html');
   if(link == '3') jQuery('#content').load('htmlPage3.html');
}
```

Assuming that the div where you want to put your content has the id "content", off course you have to customize addresses that jQuery loads (htmlPage2.html ...)

Hope this helps