# How do I use the simpletip script in a frame

Tags: jquery, frame, simpletip

when using **Simple tooltips** script In the frame, half of the balloon is created in the box.
What is the solution???

http://craigsworks.com/projects/simpletip/#

frame dize:

```
<iframe scrolling="no" src="frame.php" style="width:960px; height:460px;"></iframe>
```

script:

```
$('.spot').each(function(){
    var id= $(this).attr("id");
    $(this).simpletip({
        persistent:true,focus:true, fixed: true, position:'top', showEffect:'fade', hideEffect:'fade', ![enter image description here][3]content:'<div class="intip"><img src="o/wait30.gif"></div>',onShow: function(){this.load('spot.php',{b:id,c:1});}
    });
});
```

[Another photo for example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hC8CO.png)

please help me

Comment: Showz me dez codz!? Your question is quite unsolvable the way it is without a clearer explanation and an example (or some markup code) we can take a look at.

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/hC8CO.png   Another photo for example

Comment: Do not use `iframe`s as simple as that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, your asking how to avoid having your tooltips within an iframe being hidden when they appear past their border.

As far as I could tell, you can't achieve that effect. Not to mention, iframes are deprecated and bad karma and all that stuff, so really unless you can't avoid it, you shouldn't be using it. Regardless, I'm quite confident you can't have the effect your looking for.

You can adjust the position of your tooltips with that script, so you can simply specify a visible area, however this isn't a very scalable option.

Best of luck, and as @Shef has mentioned, you should really offer a clearer explanation.

Comment: >.< "iFrame". It's not an Apple product!

Comment: Oh, and iframes are not deprecated at all. [HTML5 even adds stuff to them!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/755795/are-iframes-html-obsolete).

Comment: Alright, 'at one time deprecated' would be more accurate. The point remains that their best left for situations where no alternative exists.

Answer (score 1):

It's not a "box". It's an iframe, a separate document embedded in your window. Everything inside it is self-contained. Not even the `seamless` property (in HTML5) can change this.

The solution is not to use iframes here.