# Display external web page in HTML5 app, while keeping own menu

Tags: html

I am developing an HTML5 web app that is mostly being used on mobile devices. It's basically a link discovery app: It shows the user some hopefully interesing links, which the user then can visit. I would like to keep the user in our app though, so that our menu bar always remains at top.

Standard links of course take the users away from our page completely, with no option to return:

```
<a href="https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1561455954" rel="nofollow noreferrer">The Cheshire Cheese Cat</a>
```

`frames` and `iframes` are discouraged in HTML5. What other options are there?

(What we try to achieve is similar to what Facebook or Twitter are doing. Lots of links are being passed around there, which the user can visit. But he alsway can go back to his news feed, with the Facebook or Twitter menu bar.

Comment: I think you can create something like proxy for http requests in web ui, and add, for example script tag to the end of html page.

Answer (score -1):

If you just want to make links open in a new tab (which is what I would recommend), you can simply use `target="_blank"`:

```
<!-- opens in a new tab/window (depending on the user's browser) -->
<a href="http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1561455954" target="_blank">The Cheshire Cheese Cat</a>
```

Comment: The user can always close the tab or switch to the previous tab to get back to your site. Having your app's navbar on top of a different site will be complicated without frames or proxies.

Answer (score -1):

Man I think you have to make a good research about HTML5

Html 5 is only a `upgrade` (in quotes) to the existence html and javascript, `iframes` are totally valid element and `frame` you are right they are deprecated. But for at least you dont want to use them or other, iframe are a good way to go for what you want to achieve. If you are going in the iOS or Android plataform I dont sure but I guess should exist some kind of `browser object` which is what use facebook.

I think you have problems with the cross domain control policy and not because the `iframe` tag

take a look to this answer

[Alternative to iFrames with HTML5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8702704/alternative-to-iframes-with-html5)

best

And HTML5 is no a new framework is just html and javascript.