# Jquery mobile popup data-role making problems

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-mobile, iframe

I am using a "Jquery Mobiles popup" for displaying ads, the code looks pretty much like this:

```
<div data-role="popup" id="adsPage" data-theme="b" class="ui-content">
  <img id="x" src="@routes.Assets.at("images/x.png")" onclick="closeAd()"/>
  <iframe id="adsFrame" src="/ads"></iframe>
</div>
```

The problem is this `data-role = popup` messes up my whole page. Always when another page is loading, suddenly the popup appears for a second, also messing with the whole layout of the pages.

I tried several solutions for this problem but none did work, so far.

---

Obviously I tried to use `data-role = page` first, but in this case the iframe wouldn't show any content

---

I tried to set the opacity to 0, and only setting it to 1 before opening it, this made half of all pages clickable with the href of the iframe content.

---

I also tried to set the display of the div to none, and only setting in to block before the popup was openend. In this case I couldn`t see any content when the ads was opened.

---

My last approach was to set the div initially to `data-role = page` and then

```
if( adCount >= 20 ) {
    adCount = 0;
    $( "#adsFrame" ).attr("data-role", "popup");
    window.location.replace('#adsPage');
}
```

This didn`t work either, but I am not sure if the code is wrong.

---

So my question is, can I make the last solution work? Or can someone explain to me why the iframe wouldn't show any content when `data-role = page` is selected, and if I could fix this somehow? Or any other kind of solution comes to your mind?

Thanks for any piece of input in advance.

Comment: Did you look at these demos: http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.5/popup-iframe/ ?

Comment: Yes sadly with this width resizing the ad wouldnt show up either

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could fix this issue using an embedded object instead of the iframe. The embedded object could be used without problems in the jquery mobile page, so the layout of my app wouldn't get messed up anymore from the popup.

The idea I got here:
[Alternative to iFrames with HTML5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8702704/alternative-to-iframes-with-html5)