# How can I modify the web page produced by an external application without modifying the application?

Tags: html

I have the following problem: I have a frontend application A that authenticates, sets up a reverse proxy, and then forwards to a separate application B I don't control.

I would like to add decorations to the resulting page of the B application, for example adding a button "logout", but I can't modify B's code or templates.

Is there some magic trick I don't know about to obtain this result?

Comment: Your tag HTML is a bit, lonely. Do you have more context?

Comment: @Roberrrt: I would if I knew what I am talking about, but if I did, I wouldn't be here asking :)

Comment: Fair play, hehe. My first instinct says: 'no' you cannot modify an external page from a different source, but there are some contextual sideways that would work on certain conditions. Take a bookmarklet (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bookmarklet) as an example.

Comment: I can give the details of the actual application frameworks, but I doubt they are relevant. One (the frontend, A) is a tornado app. The other (the secondary app, B) is a flask app. A logs the user in, starts B, sets up a reverse proxy, then forwards you to the url associated with B.

Comment: @Roberrrt However, B is a mess, I don't want to touch it, it's a bad idea to do so for other reasons. Yet, the user experience it gives would be improved if I could add decorations on top of it, such as a logout button, and a button that brings you back to the application A main page.

Comment: Is it possible to include application B inside an `<iframe>` and have the decorations as a fixed header?

Comment: Uhm... iframe sounds plausible as an approach. Not trivial but I guess I can obtain something. I though it was deprecated though...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8702704/alternative-to-iframes-with-html5

Comment: @Roberrrt That's a great reply. Thank you. Could you please post it as an answer so I can mark it as resolved?

Comment: I've wrapped the discussion inside an answer, so future viewers can see them as well. Good luck with your application!

Comment: When you're proxying B through A, A could rewrite the HTML on the fly to insert or modify elements. It's "just" a bit of DOM manipulation at the proxy. This is a pretty ugly situation and you never know when it's going to break, but it's certainly *possible*.

Comment: @deceze In practice, the proxying is done by a node.js reverse proxy, which is pretty simple and just forwards the request. I could technically do that, but I would have to change the revproxy completely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your case, as discussed in the comments, leaves you open for a couple options:

- **Wrap application b inside an `<iframe>`**

Load application b inside an `<iframe>`, while keeping a custom navigation bar in the top on a fixed position. This would be possible if the `<iframe>` is hosted on the same location as application b. This would avoid tampering with the original code of application b, while still giving you freedom to alter the user experience.

Example:

`<iframe src="https://mdn-samples.mozilla.org/snippets/html/iframe-simple-contents.html" width="400" height="300">
    <p>Your browser does not support iframes.</p>
</iframe>`

(variation on this):

```
<object data="http://www.web-source.net" width="600" height="400">
    <embed src="http://www.web-source.net" width="600" height="400"> </embed>
     Error: Embedded data could not be displayed.
</object>
```

Alternatively, this is a great related question with some viable solutions:
[Alternative to iFrames with HTML5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8702704/alternative-to-iframes-with-html5)

- **Insert custom JavaScript / CSS inside application b**

If you have control over the code of application b, you could include a small JavaScript file that automatically inserts some absolute elements to enhance the user experience. It would avoid to ruin the original code, but it's not really a clean solution

- **Modify the existing code**

It's an option, but you shouldn't if you're not comfortable to edit it. Because you'll most likely waste a lot of time on it.

Good luck with your application!