# joomla importing a webpage without iframe

Tags: joomla, joomla3.0

I would like to show a webpage on a Joomla website:

the webpage is complete and works in an iframe but its a complex page making it very slow when running in an iframe.

is there any way to not use a iframe?

this is the iframe:

```
<p> <iframe src="testpage/" width="100%" height="600"></iframe></p>
```

i have kind of given up on this for now. is there anyway i could show a different page depending on if its a phone? this way it would fix the speed problem.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/8702704/1983389

Comment: thanks but i havent found one that isnt very slow yet. the problem mainly occurs on android phones. its good on pc/mac and ok on ios phones.