# How can I copy text elements from one webpage to another?

Tags: html

I am currently working on designing a website that is centered around video content. I have a section on the home page called Featured Videos that simply has img tags with a YouTube thumbnail inside of them and a p tag underneath with the name relevant to each thumbnail.

On all the other pages I would like to have the featured videos section included as well, is there a way I can make the relevant img link and p tag with the name copy over to all the the other pages?

Comment: Do you hardcode the featured videos with html or are you generating the content with another language? There are several ways to include other html files into multiple pages. I found this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/31845361/2601107 which summarizes the current alternatives well.

Comment: yeah its simply html and some css styling, had a read of the thread you posted. seemed they were more talking about video content. my featured videos section is simply jus thumbnail images so all i need to copy over from the home page is a few url's from the <img> tags? which im guessing can be individually identified by assigning unique ID's to each one

Comment: So you should seperate your featured videos into a sperate html file. Afterwards you can include it in multiple files using the <iframe> tag which is pure html. If you want to use JavaScript and jQuery as well you can also include extra content using AJAX.

Comment: You can just use same method as on homepage, It's hard to say anything more because of lack of information of the solution used on main page

Comment: would the method you describe allow me to change how the section is layed out on the other pages though? i have them styled differently in terms of where they are on the page and some sizing. thats why im wondering if theres a way to jus simply access the urls and text content of the names and have them inputted into the <img> tags and <p> tags on the other page with different layout.

Comment: You might include the featured videos file which only contains the img and p tags. Then you can style them differently using css.