# How to isolate from main application an email with html body that contains css import

Tags: html, css, iframe, html-email

I have created a webmail client application developed via [AngularJS](https://angularjs.org/)

The email body that is displayed is in HTML form.
My problem is that there are email from customers that **import css and overide my application css**  :

```
@import url("https://some.web.site/main.css");
href="https://some.web.site/css/stylesheet.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
```

I've investigated a little bit and found that [iframe](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_iframe.asp) isolates the content from the web page however it is considered bad practice.
Other alternatives presented in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8702704/alternative-to-iframes-with-html5) are [object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/object) and [embed](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/embed) but they seem very similar
All require providing some src (url link)
My question is: is there a way to wrap a div that its internal content is some html that have its own styling without affecting the main (parent) elements styling (css)?

Comment: `iframe` may be the exact solution you need. It is only a bad practice to use iframe incorrectly. This seems like an appropriate case. (Pretty much every web client does that.)

Comment: `iframe` does NOT work in email. https://mailchimp.com/help/limitations-of-html-email/#Do_Not_Use

Answer (score 0):

In email, you can handle css styling in three different ways, listed below in the support they have for email clients:

Inline Style:

```
<p style="font-weight: bold;">&nbsp;</p>
```

Internal Style sheet:

```
<style>
  p {font-weight: bold;}
</style>
```

External Style sheet:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mystyle.css">
```

The best all-around approach is to use an Internal Style Sheet. It works with most email clients and if you are doing responsive development, it's the most common supported way to do `@madia` queries. The problem with an External Style sheet is that Outlook and Gmail will not work with one, which really limits the audience.

You should run a script for Angular to pull out the styles used in your email and collate them in a style sheet in the head of your html email.

Good luck.

Comment: Thanks however I dont create the email. The email is a third party that my webmail client presents. I was trying to avoid the css of the email that affected the webmail client application css. Anyhow I think that only way is to isolate the mail presentations using iframes

Comment: `iframe` doesn't work in email. - https://mailchimp.com/help/limitations-of-html-email/#Do_Not_Use