# Call Different domain in dialog window

Tags: html, ajax, iframe

I want to remove the dependency of Iframe from my application. What are the possible way I can call a different application URL other than using iframe, object or html embeded variable.

I am trying something like this.

`<body>
    <a class="ajax" href="http://www.google.com">
        Open in Modal Window
    </a>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function (){
            $('a.ajax').click(function() {
                var url = this.href;
                var dialog = $('<div style="display:none" class="Waiting"></div>').appendTo('body');
                dialog.dialog({
                    close: function(event, ui) {
                        dialog.remove();
                    },
                    modal: true
                });
                dialog.load(
                    url,
                    {}, 
                    function (responseText, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest) {
                        dialog.removeClass('Waiting');
                    }
                );
                return false;
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>`

Comment: Iframe is for emdeed another page into context. What you mean with remove? I don't understand what you want. Post some piece of code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Alternative to iFrames with HTML5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8702704/alternative-to-iframes-with-html5)

Comment: I want to call a cross domain url in a div or pop up window and once the window is close or div is hide user should go back to parent domain. how can I achieve this without using iframe .

Answer (score 0):

sorry can't comment 
assuming there's no no anti CSF or similar measures on the target website you can use JavaScript `ajax`
or do it server side by grabbing the site

for better help describe what you're trying to archive what you did providing sample code if possible

Comment: can you comment how to do it in server side without redirect the entire website.