# Alternatives for Single SPA

Tags: javascript, reactjs, angular, micro-frontend, single-spa

I've tried implementing a micro frontend using Single SPA but I also need to explore any other alternatives which can combine both angular and react and deploy into a single application.I've explored mooa which I did not feel it much useful for angular and react. Can anyone suggest any better micro frontend framework? **My main use case is to use both angular and react combined into one application like Header is an angular and body is a react application.**?

Comment: Seems like more headaches than benefit trying to run both in same page.

Comment: Although it always sounded painful to me, there are many places even today that do this with `<iframe>`s...

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8702704/alternative-to-iframes-with-html5. And
https://css-tricks.com/the-simplest-ways-to-handle-html-includes/

Comment: http://dodo.mikosoft.info - The Dodo as an alternative framework. Blazing fast, easy to learn, Javascript, frontend framework for reactive web pages & apps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ai852f) In one of my application I use angular as base project and in one page I used Iframe for one application which one was .net mvc.

So as a way, you can use react application inside `<iframe>` in angular application

Comment: Other than Iframe is there any already ready application to use like SIngle-SPA

Comment: It doesn't seem possible without iframe for this combination. I haven't seen or heard anything about this without iframe